# Is using a domain object as a form-backing object in Spring MVC a bad practice?

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc, dto

Would it be a bad practice to use an instance of Event as a form-backing object in Spring MVC?

One of the problems with this approach comparing to DTOs is that a client can change the hidden fields in a view and that you need to check and reset them.
But are there any others?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Event
    {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "event_id")
    public int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    public User userId;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Amount can't be empty")
    public int amount;

    @Column(name = "description")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Description can't be empty")
    public String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entered_by")
    public User enteredBy;

    @Column(name = "entered_at", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date enteredAt;

    }
```

Comment: Of course bad practice, which **hidden fields**  are you talking about?

Comment: By hidden fields I mean <input type="hidden" />. It is the same for the ones that aren't included in the HTML templates but can be inserted by a client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main goal of DTOs is, as you said, isolation. 
You don't always want the client side to see/access all the fields you have on the DB side.

Moreover, you can use DTOs to aggregate multiple calls from various tables/services and get it back to the client side with one form object.

Comment: I heard a suggestion that if your classes only have setters and getters (i. e., no complex logic), you can reuse them as DTOs. My main problem with separate DTOs is that you have to duplicate large portions of the already defined classes.

This is why I wanted to find out if there are other drawbacks to this approach of reusing domain objects.